# java sql SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)!

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
try { 
    int stupac=tabZaDijagnozu.getSelectedRow();
    String T=(tabZaDijag.getModel().getValueAt(stupac,0).toString());
    String sql="SELECT *FROM dijagnoze WHERE ID='"+T+"'";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();

   if(rs.next()) {
       String id=rs.getString("ID");     
       String Query = "DELETE *FROM dijagnoze WHERE ID='"+id+"'";
       pst=conn.prepareStatement(Query);
       pst.setString(1, "ID");
       pst.execute();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted!");
    }      
} catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

I tried to figure it out by myself looking into other similar posts but it just didnt work.

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have any parameters in your SQL.  In your code you are building the SQL but appending the value

Change to

```
String Query = "DELETE FROM dijagnoze WHERE ID = ?";
pst=conn.prepareStatement(Query);
pst.setString(1, id);
```

**edit**

Also, your select should be fixed at least to the below (but using parameters would be safer to protect from sql injection)

```
String sql="SELECT * FROM dijagnoze WHERE ID = '" + T + "'";
```

**edit2**

In your code you are firstly doing a `select` based upon id, then if that record exists, you are doing a `delete`.  It is not necessary to so the `select` first, just `delete`.